# Building latex with pipeline - pdf with wrong page order

Tags: docker, latex, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I am using pipeline to build a latex document in Gitlab. Everything works except the page order is mixed up (eg. 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, ...).

This is the content of the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
compile_pdf:
image: aergus/latex
script:
    - latexmk -pdf main.tex
artifacts:
    paths:
        - main.pdf
tags:
    - docker
```

Two completely different latex projects produce mixed up pdfs.

Comment: It doesn't look like a gitlab-related problem. Are you sure your .tex file is correct ?

Comment: If I run these on my computer with TexStudio using pdflatex everything works.

Comment: The PDF Viewer ob Gitlab is causing the problem. Downloading the pdf to my computer and viewing it there works fine.